# Check for empty input fields in laravel

Tags: laravel, lumen

I have a lot of input fields that gets posted. I want to loop through them all to see whether some of them are empty or not and then depending on the result call different functions.

Currently i check all the fields one by one like this:

```
    if($request->has('my_firstname') && !empty($request->input('my_firstname'))) {
        
    } else {
     
    }
```

I got like 18 fields to check so continue like this feels inefficent. I have tried something like this, but that gives me too little control.

```
$input->all();
```

How would i do this?

Comment: How about you use manual validator and pass the request data from your validator

Comment: take a look at that https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#form-request-validation

Answer (score 0):

I did this, which works just great.

```
    foreach($request->all() as $key => $value) {
        if(empty($value)) {
            $status = false;
        } else {
            $this->export();
            $status = true;
        }
    }
```